# How to show phone orientation on google maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, android-maps-utils

I have a GoogleMap object. Map is visible, all OK. On the map we can see a standart blue marker - current position of user. Sometimes this marker shows us an arrow - phone orientation (were we are looking now). Question: what me must do to ALWAYS show this arrow?

[example 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6MRn1.png)

Or maybe you can tell me, how to enable "navigator mode" with screen rotation (example 2)?

[example 2](https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/graphics/navigation-car.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer:
Arrow not shows, when you use wi-fi! If you go on the street with GCM or GPS, arrow will be visible!:)